# AngularJS is not validating my form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know Angular pretty well, use it everyday, but apparently, I'm having one of those days..

I'm probably missing something hideously obvious, but why aren't I seeing `testForm.testField.$invalid` & `testForm.testField.$dirty`  etc???

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <form name="testForm">
        <input type="text" name="testField" ng-model="testField" required="required" />
        {{testForm | json}}    
        {{testField}}
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm new in angular, but I see that testField is part of the angular model (there is a ng-model="testField"), but I cannot see testForm as part of it

Comment: @Pablo No worries, when you have a form in angular, the name of the form will be the variable in the scope, that refers to it. Alternatively you can do: ng-form="myVariableName".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the Angular source, the conversion to JSON says:

> Properties with leading $ characters will be stripped since angular
>   uses this notation internally.

Unfortunately the documentation for the `json` filter doesn't mention that.

See https://github.com/gaborcs/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js lines 930-931.

Comment: That's it! Thanks ! Was slightly less obvious than I thought it would be!